# How to change password using php and my sql?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Hi i  have a php page where i wrote some html and php code for change password  and it is working fine when i run this page on localhost  directly.

but when i include this page  in any another html page and use it does not work

here is my code

**changepassword.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
$eid=$_SESSION['eid'];
echo $eid;

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
mysql_select_db("helixcrm",$conn);
if(count($_POST)>0) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *from login WHERE eid='" . $eid . "'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);


if($_POST["currentPassword"] == $row["password"]) {
mysql_query("UPDATE login set password='" . $_POST["newPassword"] . "' WHERE eid='" . $eid . "'");
$message = "Password Changed";
} else $message = "Current Password is not correct";
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Change Password</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<script>
function validatePassword() {
var currentPassword,newPassword,confirmPassword,output = true;

currentPassword = document.frmChange.currentPassword;
newPassword = document.frmChange.newPassword;
confirmPassword = document.frmChange.confirmPassword;

alert(i+j+k);

if(!currentPassword.value) {
    currentPassword.focus();
    document.getElementById("currentPassword").innerHTML = "required";
    output = false;
}
else if(!newPassword.value) {
    newPassword.focus();
    document.getElementById("newPassword").innerHTML = "required";
    output = false;
}
else if(!confirmPassword.value) {
    confirmPassword.focus();
    document.getElementById("confirmPassword").innerHTML = "required";
    output = false;
}
if(newPassword.value != confirmPassword.value) {
    newPassword.value="";
    confirmPassword.value="";
    newPassword.focus();
    document.getElementById("confirmPassword").innerHTML = "not same";
    output = false;
}   
return output;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frmChange" method="post" action="" onSubmit="return validatePassword()">
<div style="width:500px;">
<div class="message"><?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } ?></div>
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="500" align="center" class="tblSaveForm">
<tr class="tableheader">
<td colspan="2">Change Password</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="40%"><label>Current Password</label></td>
<td width="60%"><input type="password" name="currentPassword"  id="currentpassword"class="txtField"/><span id="currentPassword"  class="required"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>New Password</label></td>
<td><input type="password" name="newPassword"  id="newpassword" class="txtField"/><span id="newPassword" class="required"></span></td>
</tr>
<td><label>Confirm Password</label></td>
<td><input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id ="confirmpassword"class="txtField"/><span id="confirmPassword" class="required"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body></html>
```

this  page working fine  when i write code like this it does not work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#resetpassword").click(function() {
                    $(function() {
                        $("#RightPaneContainerDiv").load("changepassword.php");
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Reset Password

Here above code is not working

How can i achieve my output

Thanks in advance

Comment: Define "not working". Do you get an error? What's the expected behavior and what happens instead?

Comment: i am not getting any error  it send me on  back index page back thats it

Comment: http://rs1img.memecdn.com/Urban-SQL-injection_o_80492.webp

Comment: Was I just transported back to 1996?! Holy cow. Stop using `mysql(...)` methods, and read this: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info under the title "How do I make my database queries secure from SQL injection?"

Answer (score 0):

You cant load a complete html page into a div in another page. 
Perhaps the easiest thing to do would be to use an iframe:

```
$("#resetpassword").click(function() {
      $(function() {
          $("#RightPaneContainerDiv").html('<iframe class="cpassword" src="changepassword.php"></iframe>');
      });
});
```

Styled appropriatly with css